# using django respassword_reset_confirm error ,

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 2.1 and getting an error during password reset authentication right at the end.

**my urls**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy, resolve


app_name = 'partners'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='partner_home'),
    url(r'^(?P<partner_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^login/$',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="partners/registration/login.html"), name="login"),
    url(r'^logout/$',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name="partners/registration/logout.html"), name="logout"),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^profile/$', views.view_profile, name='view_profile'),
    url(r'^profile/edit/$', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),

    # Password URL's ###################################################################################################

    url(r'^change-password/$', views.change_password, name='change_password'),


    url(
        r'^password_reset/$',
        auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
            template_name="partners/registration/password_reset.html",
            email_template_name="partners/registration/password_reset_email.html",
            success_url=reverse_lazy("partners:password_reset_done"),  # might be required
        ),
        name='password_reset'
    ),

    url(r'^password_reset_done/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
            template_name="registration/password_reset_done.html",
        ),
        name='password_reset_done'
    ),


    url(r'^password_reset_confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
        # r'(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
            template_name="registration/password_reset_confirm.html",
        ),
        name='password_reset_confirm',
    ),


    url(r'^password_reset_complete/$',
        auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
            template_name="partners/registration/password_reset_complete.html",
        ),
        name="password_reset_complete"
    ),
]
```

I am able to login, then  go to the password reset view. An email is sent using the development server and I am able to use the link to create a new password. Once I enter the new password I get an error (but the password in the background is changed). I am not sure why this is the case at the moment .

**I am not using my custom password_reset_xxx html file instead I am using the builtin views**

**My URLS and structure**

[image]

**The Error Message**

[image: The Error Message]

Comment: Please don't post errors as screenshots. Use the *Switch to copy-and-paste view* link, and then include the traceback as text.

Answer (score 0):

You have put your password reset urls in the `partners` app, therefore you need to override the code wherever it reverses urls so that it uses the `partners` namespace.

In this case, you need to override `success_url` in `PasswordResetConfirmView`.

```
    auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
        template_name="registration/password_reset_confirm.html",
        success_url = reverse_lazy('partners:password_reset_complete')
    ),
```

However, you may find there are other places that you need to override to get the password reset working. As I suggested on your other question, it would be simpler to move the password reset URLs out of the `partners` app.